# Object such as Random (Local and instance variables)

Tags: java

Let's say I have the class below:
Each time Meow calls a new Random object is creating on the heap.

```
public class Cat {
    public void Meow() {
        Random rand = new Random(); 
        if (rand.nextInt() == 0) {
            System.out.println("Meow...");
        }
    }
}
```

Should I take the Random object out from the Meow method and change it from Local Variable to Instance Variable like this?
So each time Meow calls the same Random object attaches to the cat object that was created on the heap would be used and not a new one like in the approach above.

```
public class Cat {
    Random rand; 
    public Cat(){
        rand = new Random(); 
    }

    public void Meow() {
        if (rand.nextInt() == 0) {
            System.out.println("Meow...");
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to understand if the second approach is a best practice because even if my program small and it will not be a big problem maybe later if the program getting bigger it will help me prevent problems of performance.

Comment: I do think that you should create a Random object in an instance variable. Not because it saves any time or space, but because the random numbers will be better, IMHO.

Comment: I'd say that with such a small example it doesn't really matter. There are cases where you want an instance variable and cases when you want a local variable. But, as said by NomadMaker, time and space should be a later concern. Unless you're asking specifically about randomization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you should – I'd even say *must* – reuse a single `Random` object. Otherwise, you will end up with the same numbers, if the method is called in quick succession.

PRNG (pseudo-random number generators) work by taking an initial seed value and then transforming it over and over again to produce a deterministic sequence of number. The same seed will produce the same "random" numbers.

**NB** If you need (true?) randomness suitable for cryptographic or security-sensitive operations, avoid the class `Random` and sibling `ThreadLocalRandom` at all costs. In that case, it is crucial to use a class which provides a cryptographically strong random number generator, such as [`SecureRandom`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/security/SecureRandom.html).

---

**EDIT:** I just checked [the OpenJDK source](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/Random.java) of the `Random` class and it looks like special handling is done as to make multiple invocations of `new Random()` hopefully produce different sequences (i.e. are seeded with different initial values). However, you cannot rely on it.

Using a static field, you are not dependent on implementation details of the `Random` constructor.

But read on …

---

Even better than an instance field is a class field (i.e. `static`). Otherwise, multiple instances would again likely produce the same sequence of results.

```java
public class Cat {
  private static final Random RANDOM = new Random();
  public void Meow() {
    if (RANDOM.nextBoolean()) {
      // do meow
    }
  }
}
```

Why is this important? `new Random()` seeds the random number generator with the current process uptime. Consider the following:

```java
final Cat cat = new Cat();
cat.meow();
cat.meow(); // likely to produce the same random number as the previous line.
```

Converting to an instance variable has the same drawback:

```java
final Cat garfield = new Cat();
final Cat hobbes = new Cat(); // again likely to use the same seed
garfield.meow();
hobbes.meow();
```

A static field has another benefit: you save memory. Only one instance of `Random` exists globally (for this class) instead of one Random instance per Cat. Depending on the number of cats you plan to have in your program, the savings could make a difference.

There's on caveat though: `Random` instances are threadsafe (which is good), but if accessed from multiple threads, they can be a bottleneck.

From the [JavaDoc of `Random`](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11/blob/19fb8f93c59dfd791f62d41f332db9e306bc1422/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/Random.java#L61):

> Instances of `java.util.Random` are threadsafe.
> However, the concurrent use of the same `java.util.Random`
> instance across threads may encounter contention and consequent
> poor performance. Consider instead using
> [java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.html) in multithreaded
> designs.

How to use a [`ThreadLocalRandom`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.html)?

```java
public void meow() {
  if (ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextBoolean()) {
    // do meow
  }
}
```

You cannot store the current ThreadLocalRandom in a field, because then it would leak to different threads. Make sure that one instance of this class is only accessed by a single thread. If used in a tight loop, store it in a local variable and re-use that variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can do both. If you want to use the random number on other methods you can declare it globally. But if you will only use it in the method it was declared you can declare it locally.

As for performance. I don't think there will be an issue because I haven't encountered a performance issue when coding. Try to check the comment on this [post](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/44139/which-is-better-performance-using-a-disposable-local-variable-or-reusing-a-glob) "do not worry too much about performance until you have performance issues".